# Filter from mat-table column names in drop down and its value in text input in Angular 7/8/9

Tags: angular, filter, mat-table

I am looking for adding a Multi-filter condition.

For eg my mat-table looks like: **Name**   **Fav color**    **Vehicle**
                                   Raj         green           Car
                                   Ben         white           SUV
                                   Josh        Blue            bike

I need (Name,Fav color,vehicle) as dropdown and near by a text field, where i can type in Values (Ben or Blue or SUV) to filter it.

I am totally new to Angular

Answer (score 0):

you can simply look at the example in angular material documentation for **filter example**: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

https://stackblitz.com/angular/gabyarlkmjr?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-filtering-example.html

Similarly, around input box (refer link) you need to have a drop down as per requirement and can add logic on change of select box or like which value is selected in select box, search will filter via that.